# How do I allow www-data to change folder permissions when using Docker and pdftohtmlEX to make the folder?

Tags: docker, permissions, chmod, amazon-lightsail

EDIT: **I have found the problem** *I'm using user/group 1000:1000 but it needed to be 1:1, after adding the right user to the right group. What a n00b. Hopefully someone else will find this and it'll save them the time I lost beating my head against the wrong problem lol*

I have Docker (so I can use pdf2htmlEX) running on a Lightsail instance for dev purposes. This is all working fine using this:

```
exec('docker run --rm -v ' . $fileLoc . ':/pdf -u 1000:1000 bwits/pdf2htmlex pdf2htmlEX --embed cfijo --split-pages 1 --zoom 1 --dest-dir presentations/' . $presName . ' --page-filename content-%d.page temp_pdf/' . $filename . ' 2>&1', $output, $retVal);
```

Note: I'm having to tell Docker to be user 1000:1000 so it can make the folder and files.

The trouble is, the folder `$presName` ends up having chmod of 700 and it needs to be 755, while all the files are awesome with a lovely 644. I cannot for the life of me get these permissions to update...

I've tried every command I can think of/find on the internet:

```
exec('docker run --rm -u 1000:1000 chmod 755 ' . $fileLoc . '/presentations/' . $presName);
exec('sudo chmod 755 ' . $fileLoc . '/presentations/' . $presName);
exec('echo my-password-was-here | /usr/bin/sudo -S chmod 755 ' . $fileLoc . '/presentations/' . $presName);
exec("bash -lc 'echo my-password-was-here | /usr/bin/sudo -S chmod 755 ' . $fileLoc . '/presentations/' . $presName'");
```

None of these do anything.

"No problem!" I thought, loudly, I'll just use PHP to make the folder with the right permissions so it already exists... but alas no, PHP cannot even use `mkdir`.

I am out of my depth with this because I have never used Docker and, as best I can make out, something something container, something something user. ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

I've spent days beating my head against this. I just (lol "just") would like the folder to be 755! That's all I need...

Is there a simple solution? Is there something I can type into the terminal? Can I modify the Docker config to fix this? Or is this going to be hugely complex and I'll have to digest all the Docker documentation and become an expert?

[Edit: I used this https://hub.docker.com/r/bwits/pdf2htmlex/]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to put the file in the command of WORK DIR at the end of the image process when you are building the image for the container. If you view this document by Docker they recommend using the WORK DIR command to be able to then run things with the right user privileges.

Link to document: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir

Quote from Docker: "the WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile. If the WORKDIR doesn’t exist, it will be created even if it’s not used in any subsequent Dockerfile instruction."

The command: `WORKDIR /warmup`

I use this command for running .NET in a container, just make sure after you do the WORKDIR command you then finish with `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` so that Docker knows where to run from and what is being passed to it.

Also, I know you are building on Light sale but there is a fantastic book by "Elton Stoneman called Docker on Windows," and this is where I learnt the most about Docker. I can't recommend this book enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

This is the Docker file I used and it has `WORK DIR` set to `/pdf`: 

https://github.com/BWITS/pdf2htmlEX_docker/blob/master/Dockerfile 

But I'm currently outputting to `presentations/' . $presName . '` is this the source of my problem? `$presName` is never the same though would changing `presentations` to pdf make this problem go away?

Comment: I would change the /pdf to /presentations. I don't understand why you have put volume then work directory. As when you do Work Directory. Docker will make a sub-container containing the work dir you have specified. Also with the CMD command that you have put. I don't understand, what are you wanting to pass to the docker container when running it?

Comment: I don't understand any of it because it's not my docker file ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ 

I presumed, since this person was making it publicly available for doing specifically what I'm trying to do, that it would be at least mostly correct. 

I'm literally just doing what they said to do: https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/wiki/Download

Comment: From what I can work out, if you change the pdf to presentation then it should work as long as you use the following command: alias pdf2htmlEX="docker run -ti --rm -v ~/presentation:/presentation bwits/pdf2htmlex-alpine pdf2htmlEX" 
Then the following two commands: 
pdf2htmlEX -h 
pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 yourpdf.pdf

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, Jason, unfortunately it's not fixed my problem. I set up a whole new Lightsail to test this (and got it "working" the same as before). While running your commands instead does still convert the PDF to HTML, it outputs to the same folder as the source PDF. If I try and output to a new folder, I end up with a folder that has chmod 700. It seems to always create files with 644 and folders with 700.